# How to reduce space between label and text box in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I want to reduce space between label and text box, you can see in bellow image,
I used **Ext.form.field.Text**  control of ext JS. Please see bellow code for this control.

```
this.temp1min = new Ext.form.field.Text({
            xtype: 'textfield',
            /*  *///labelAlign: 'left',
            //labelWidth: 60,
            //width: '7%',
            //labelStyle: 'padding: 10px 10px;',
            //padding:'0 '
            fieldLabel: 'T1 Min',
            blankText: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_REQUIRED_ERROR_'),
            //allowBlank: false,
            name: 'temp1min'
        });
        this.temp1max = new Ext.form.field.Text({
            xtype: 'textfield',
            //labelAlign: 'left',
            //labelWidth: 30,
            //width: '6%',
            fieldLabel: 'T1 Max',
            blankText: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_REQUIRED_ERROR_'),
            // allowBlank: false,
            name: 'temp1max'
        });
```

And UI, Please see below image.
[image]

Comment: Are you using  css in addition to js to control style? Please post if so. Also, why are you commenting the width and labelwidth lines in your js?

Comment: You can see other text control T2Min, T2Max I did uncomment that code for this control

Answer (score 4):

> You can use `labelWidth:'auto';`

The [labelWidth](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-labelWidth) of the fieldLabel in pixels. Only applicable if the labelAlign is set to "left" or "right".

Here I have created an [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/298m) demo. Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Label width example',
    width: '100%',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    defaults: {
      xtype: 'textfield',
        labelWidth: 'auto',
        margin: '0 5',
        allowBlank: false // requires a non-empty value
    },
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'T1 Min',
        name: 'temp1min'
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'T1 Max',
        name: 'temp1min'
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
    }, {
        name: 'email',
        fieldLabel: 'Email Address',
        vtype: 'email' // requires value to be a valid email address format
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Labelwidth: 'auto'
```

does not work in extjs 6.0.x, it only accepts numbers.

edit: Found the answer.

To adjust the space between the label and the textfield, in extjs 6.0.x, you have to use the following code.

```
labelStyle: 'width: 30px'
```